# Передача параметров GET запроса

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

Смотрю лекции по rails, возник вопрос:
Вот например юзверь послал такой запрос:

```
http://exmaple.com/find/?id[id]=1&id[hacker]=awesome_hacker
```

а я пишу в коде `Users.find(params.id)`, то в модельку передадуться все параметры.
Как этого избежать? Если напишу `User.find(params.require(:id))`, ничего не изменится.

Answer (score 3):

`params[:id][:id]` ?

Comment: Не совсем вас понимаю. Задача-то в том, чтобы id не был объектом, а мог быть только число, как для этого отфильтровать данные? Или только в модели фильтр поставить?

Comment: Тогда проблема в том что ты отправляешь, а не как обрабатываешь. Показывай форму, что уж там.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос довольно интересный.

**params** – это не просто хеш, а объект определенного класса.

**require** получает значение хэша по ключу.

**permit** определяет разрешенные параметры в  ресурсе для передачи их значений в контроллер. Указываем только то, что хотим получить. Если тут не указывать hacker - то его обрабатывать контроллер не будет.

[Всё, что нужно знать о роутах, парамсах и формах в рельсах](https://mkdev.me/posts/vsyo-chto-nuzhno-znat-o-routes-params-i-formah-v-rails)
[ActionController::Parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html)